# Spring Data JPA persisting one to many referenced entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, reference

I am using Spring Data JPA (1.4.0, spring boot) and have following code

ExternalOrder entity:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "External_Orders")
 public class ExternalOrder {
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "externalOrder", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ExternalOrderElement> elements;

    ...
}
```

ExternalOrderElement entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "External_Order_Elements")
public class ExternalOrderElement implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ExternalOrderID")
    private ExternalOrder externalOrder;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BoardGameID")
    private BoardGame boardGame;

    ...
}
```

I also have default Crud repository for ExternalOrder

```
public interface ExternalOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<ExternalOrder, Integer>{

}
```

And I want to add some element to external order and persist it. I've managed to do this creating my custom repostitory interface and implementing it, but I've now tried to move the logic to the service method like so:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addElementToExternalOrder(int externalOrderId, ExternalOrderElement element) {
    ExternalOrder externalOrder = findExternalOrderById(externalOrderId);

    element.setExternalOrder(externalOrder);
    externalOrder.getElements().add(element);

    externalOrderRepository.save(externalOrder);
}
```

And that results in following Exception upon execution

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ExternalOrderID' cannot be null
```

Is there something I am missing about the JPA? It seems like I haven't set the ExternalOrder reference on ExternalOrderElement, but I've done it.

Thank you guys for help in advance.

Comment: How can externalOrder be the Id of your element entity. It's a ManyToOne. So many elements have the same external order. So it can't be the ID, since the ID is supposed to uniquely identify an element. Do yourself a favor, and use autogenerated, purely technical IDs. Also, you need to realize that entities are managed. So every change you make to an entity inside a transaction is automatically saved. No need to call save().

Comment: externalOrder along with boardGame make an unique ID for element. Sorry for that I didn't cover it in the code portion (at first, now i've added). I guess you're right and I could create autogenerated for that class but let's say thats too late now for this specific project. Thank you for the information about the managed thing, i'll look for some information on that specific topic.

Comment: I've removed save() call and it works now. Thank you very much